# Why is the output of plotting a curve of high-density points in R not smooth?

Tags: r

I am plotting a count histogram of my data and then overlaying the shape of the gamma distribution that I think underlies the data. The points on the gamma distribution are generated using `dgamma` and plotted using `curve`. No matter how many points I use to generate the curve, the output still looks pixellated. Does anyone know why and is it possible to obtain a smooth curve?

```
dt <- rgamma(100, shape = 2.59, scale = 0.16)

n <- 1000
x <- seq(min(dt), max(dt), length.out = n) 

hist(dt, freq = FALSE, ylim = c(0, 2.5), xlab = "D")
curve(dgamma(x, shape = 2.59, scale = 0.16), add = TRUE, lwd = 2, n = n)
```

Comment: Your call to `curve` should give a call to the function, i.e. `curve(dgamma(x, shape=2.59, scale = 0.16), add = TRUE, lwd = 2)`.

Comment: @user2554330 ah, yes, part of the code must have disappeared when I C&P'ed to test it. Thanks, I have edited.

Comment: @InverniE Trying to execute this says 
`Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
hist"
Execution halted`.

Comment: @kitswas  , I have re-written the line and it should have disappeared now. Oddly enough, it was giving the error but executing the code anyways for me.

Comment: There is a problem in the line `x <- dgamma(c(min(dt), max(dt), n)`.

Comment: I have retyped the entire code, it works smoothly for me now.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to try the option type=l ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

curve has a `n` attribute that defaults to `101` you need to increase that. So note that not the datapoints you throw in determine your resolution.

```
curve(dgamma(x, shape = 2.59, scale = 0.16), add = TRUE, lwd = 2, n = n) # then it takes your defined n = 1000
```

Comment: I have just tried this (thanks, I had not noticed it), but it does not solve my problem: the outout line still looks very pixellated, even with 10000 points. Code edited.

Comment: Have you saved it as psd? do not get distracted by the resolution of the Viewer in RStudio. with n = 1000 your sample code looks perfectly smootht.

Comment: You are right, saving it using one of the formatting functions shows that the resolution is higher than in the Viewer. I should have thought of that.